# obj c "for loop" road block

Tags: iphone, objective-c, for-loop

Im showing some data in a simple bar that charts some values, all is working, but now to build the scale for my Y axis, im having some problems with some basic stuff,

I get the ceiling value for my chart with `scaleMaxInt` in this case for testing = 900

then according  to some simple test, I get for example 9 divisions [plus zero]...

so to make the thing work, I create the int pp=100

```
- (void) drawScaleLabels:(int)scaleMaxInt 
{

     //temp division for scale, NOTE WHERE TO USE 9 DIVISIONS!!

     int scaleStep = scaleMaxInt/9;
     NSLog(@"va ::%d", scaleStep);

     // case scaleMax : 0 < scaleMax < 1000
     float scaleDiv = 31.5;

     for (int i = 0; i<9; i++) 
     { // is 8, to 9 only for testing!!
         int pp = 100;

         self.divScaleLabel = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(469, scaleDiv+286, 60, 14)]autorelease];  
         self.divScaleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"FS Albert" size:14];
         self.divScaleLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
         self.divScaleLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentRight;
         self.divScaleLabel.text =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"$%d",scaleMaxInt-scaleStep];

         self.divScaleLabel.backgroundColor =[UIColor clearColor];
         [self.view addSubview:self.divScaleLabel];

         scaleDiv = scaleDiv + 31.5;
         scaleStep = scaleStep+pp;
     }

}
```

wich shows the list of values in my Y axis: 900 , 800 , 700 ,600... 0

but if I use the result of the  `int scaleStep = scaleMaxInt/9`

it gives me the list but with the value*2

```
- (void) drawScaleLabels:(int)scaleMaxInt 
{
    //temp division for scale, NOTE WHERE TO USE 9 DIVISIONS!!

    int scaleStep = scaleMaxInt/9;

    NSLog(@"va ::%d", scaleStep);

    // case scaleMax : 0 < scaleMax < 1000
    float scaleDiv = 31.5;

    for (int i = 0; i<9; i++) 
    { // is 8, to 9 only for testing!!

        //int pp = 100;

        self.divScaleLabel = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(469, scaleDiv+286, 60, 14)]autorelease];  
        self.divScaleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"FS Albert" size:14];
        self.divScaleLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        self.divScaleLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentRight;
        self.divScaleLabel.text =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"$%d",scaleMaxInt-scaleStep];

        self.divScaleLabel.backgroundColor =[UIColor clearColor];
        [self.view addSubview:self.divScaleLabel];

        scaleDiv = scaleDiv + 31.5;
        NSLog(@"va ::%d", scaleStep);
        scaleStep = scaleStep+scaleStep;
   }

}
```

so Y axis is, 900, 800 , 700, 500 , 100, -700 ...-24700

Im stupidly stuck with this!,

how can i generate the list for Y axis?, with a dynamic value, dependent of `scaleMaxInt`
that doesn't get confused??

thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have this in your loop:

```
scaleStep = scaleStep+scaleStep;
```

That means you are doubling `scaleStep` on each pass through the loop.  Remove that line.  Instead, set `self.divScaleLabel.text` like this:

```
self.divScaleLabel.text =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"$%d", scaleMaxInt - scaleStep * i];
```

Comment: thats it!, thanks, after 9 hours of coding, I was a bit closed of mind!, thanks again